# Is it ok to initialize a Byte array with size something more that 1024?

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

Increasing the size from 1k to 4k would facilitate fast copying of files from a directory to another. But is it ok to do so?

Target android- minAPI-16

```
byte[] myByte=new byte[1024];
```

Comment: Most Android phones have more than 4KB of memory.

Comment: You tell nothing about the context; what OS? What JRE? What version?

Comment: @fge I've re-added the Android tag initially added by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3KB of spare memory it's ok.  If you don't have this much memory, I wouldn't do it.

note:  You can't make a byte[] which is 2+ GB.

Answer (score 0):

4k is better, but you can and should increase it more. Faster copies and lower battery usage is better than saving a few kb of RAM.

For comparison, `cp` on GNU/Linux and Busybox/Android uses a buffer size of 65536 bytes to copy files.

(2018 update: GNU uses 131072 bytes now)